# How to enable VBScript for custom form?

Tags: vbscript, outlook

I created custom Outlook form based on Message form (class `IPM.Note`). I added one custom label and dropdown (now class `IPM.Note.MyCustomMessage`). I added simple script just to test if it is running.

```
Function Item_Open()
    MsgBox "Opening"
End Function
```

But nothing was hapenning. I tried with `Item_Send` too.

Then I found that it's possibly due to security settings so I modified registry to enable scripting like described here: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/custom-form-script-is-now-disabled-by-default-bd8ea308-733f-4728-bfcc-d7cce0120e94.
I also went to Trust center to Allow script in shared folders and Allow script in Public folders but still no success. Script does not run.

What else can I try?

Comment: You say 'VBScript' - is it really VBScript, or VBA?

Comment: I click ViewCode on form. There is additional button to open VisualBasic editor. Maybe I should use this?

Comment: If you're viewing the code, I would believe that you're actually using VBA (Visual Basic for Applications). I would retag your question with VBA - you're more likely to get more results that way.

Comment: VBA is something different. There are two editors.

Comment: Ah! Okay. Apologies.

Comment: Morning Piotr, I did find [this YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QV54mj43mzA) video, but I don't think it's quite what you're after. It looks like (after watching other form editing/creation videos) that there is a disassociation between coding the higher level forms and the VBA form demonstrated (though I can't be sure).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out I didn't have macros enabled. I didn't now VBScript counts as macros. I thought macros are VBA only.